# Name imported modules after <name> in the pom

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using `m2e` to import an existing maven project. The problem I am having has to do with the `Name Template`. It gives examples of different combinations of the `groupId`, `artifactId`, and `version` but not the `<name>` tag from the `pom`. Is `m2e` not able to pick up that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is possible, both from own observation as from the following issue as reported:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1216

You may upvote the issue.

However, since the `name` field is defined as being more of a conversational name, it often doesn't lend itself very well to be used for the project template. Clearly you're thinking of a usage of `name` that would be appropriate to be used in the project template, I get that.

Comment: Yeah, I did see that issue. I don't think `name` is appropriate